# Optimization Problem. Find Smallest Perimeter of a Rectangle Given Area.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, implicit-differentiation

**QUESTION**

Find the dimensions of a rectangle with area $1000$m$^2$ whose perimeter is as small as possible.

**MY WORK**

I think we are solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$:
\begin{align*}
P &= (2x+2y)  \\
A &= (x\cdot y) \\
\frac{d}{dx}1000&=\frac{d}{dx}(x \cdot y) \\
0 &=\frac{d}{dx}((x)\prime(y)+(y)\prime(x)) \\
0 &=y+x\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &=\frac{-y}{x}
\end{align*}

I didn't use the perimeter formula. I am not sure where I messed up. I think probably somewhere in my setup for the equation. If someone could take a look at my work and point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the sides of the rectangle as length $x$ and width $y$.

Given area is $xy=1000$

We need to minimize the perimeter of the rectangle. 
So, $P=2x+2y$

To minimize this, we need to differentiate $P$. Since, we have two different variables in the perimeter,  let us bring it to one variable.

We have $xy=1000\implies x=\dfrac{1000}{y}$
$$P=2\left(\dfrac{1000}{y}\right)+2y$$
$$P^{\prime}=-\dfrac{2000}{y^2}+2$$

The above equation does not exist if $y=0$

$$-\dfrac{2000}{y^2}+2=0$$
$$y^2=1000$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{1000}$$

Since the length cannot be negative we can ignore $-\sqrt{1000}$

Therefore, $y=\sqrt{1000}$ is the critical number. By plotting we can see that $y=\sqrt{1000}$ do not correspond to be local minimum, which means the perimeter of the width is minimized.

We have length $x=\dfrac{1000}{\sqrt{1000}}\implies\sqrt{1000}$ and width $y=\sqrt{1000}$

So, we can say that the perimeter of the rectangle is minimized which is actually a square.

Comment: How did you find P'? When I differentiated I used chain rule then quotient rule and got $\frac{2y-2000}{y^2}+2$

Comment: @GooseDe $\dfrac{d}{dy}\left(\dfrac1y\right)=-\dfrac{1}{y^2}$

Answer (score 1):

For minimum perimeter, put $\frac{dP}{dx} = 0$ 
$$\Longrightarrow 1+\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
$$\Longrightarrow 1+(-\frac{y}{x}) = 0$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{x-y}{x}=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow x=y$$
So perimeter will be minimum when the rectangle is a square.

Hope it is helpful

Comment: How did you get $1+\frac{dy}{dx}=0$?

Comment: By differentiating the perimeter with respect to x and cancelling off 2 on both sides.

Comment: Of course, I didn't see where it said $P=2x+2y$.

Comment: It's interesting that the same reasoning shows that a square also maximizes the area for a fixed given perimeter.

Comment: Yes, we can say that square is a rectangle which minimises the perimeter and maximises the enclosed area.